# recommendations for public facing file server

Tags: linux, open-source

I've been asked to setup a server for exchanging non-critical company data e.g. marketing PDF's etc.

Can anyone recommend a Linux-based solution I can use? We're looking for something with a really simple GUI front end here... I've already setup SFTP but they found the process 'too-techy'.

Any ideas would be really welcome...

Thanks!

Comment: FTPS will be better supported by browsers (though support isn't great, it's getting there).

Answer (score 2):

FTP is indeed quite techy for non-IT people.

I recommend [Alfresco Share](http://www.alfresco.com/products/collaboration/), it is a simple to use and powerful document-sharing platform.

[Alfresco Share http://www.alfresco.com/products/collaboration/images/document-library-multifile-upload.png](http://www.alfresco.com/products/collaboration/images/document-library-multifile-upload.png)

It can be installed on Linux as well as other operating systems.
It can scale very well, should the need arise.

To allow guest access without login, change this setting to `true`:

```
alfresco.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that Alfresco Share is free, and open source.

Answer (score 0):

If security is not an issue, you could use FTP.
Some notable versions of ftp server are '[vsftp](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/)' (which comes with RHEL/CentOS/Fedora by default) or '[proftpd](http://www.proftpd.org/)' with a simple user based authentication.

There are many guides and how-to's on the subject, some explaining more complicated setups, if for example you want to integrate your FTP server with an existing identity management server.

Comment: thanks katriel,

users didn't like SFTP so I don't think they'll like FTP either. I'm really looking for something with a web front end that they can use a hyperlink to access with a username/password, believe me 'simple' is needed with this lot ;-)

Comment: FTP can be accessed through a web browser with a simple user/password prompt. No extra software needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think any of the popular Linux distributions out there will work (I'm currently recommending Ubuntu 10.04 over RHEL/CentOS just because their repository is more convenient for me).

For customer usage, you can just stick those on a insecure/regular FTP or HTTP directory and use it as a web site. FTP should be supported by most browsers but HTTP is just plain easy.

For your internal departments to post documents to the server, their either going to need to learn how to use an S/FTP like Filezilla or you can use a web based uploader (but this will have file size restrictions).